# How to determine composite action step failure in custom GitHub Actions NodeJS notifier script within the same composite action

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-actions, cicd

I have created a custom composite action which runs a few steps. The last step is a notifier (NodeJS) script which detects if there was any failure.

So on my repository I have this action:

```yaml
name: Build & Deploy Docker

on:
  push:
    branches: ["test", "master"]

jobs:

  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build service
      uses: mydep/github-actions/service-builder@master
```

The `service-builder` action looks like this:

```yaml
name: "Service Builder"
description: "Build and push service"
author: "John Doe"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Checkout project sources
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
  
    - name: Setup Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2

    - name: Gradle Assemble
      shell: bash
      run: ./gradlew assemble

    - name: Notify Slack
      uses: mydep/github-actions/notifier@master
      if: always()
      with:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ inputs.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The `slack notifier` script which is run looks like this:

```js
import { getInput } from '@actions/core';
import { context, getOctokit } from '@actions/github';

const githubToken = getInput('GITHUB_TOKEN', { required: true });
const octokit = getOctokit(githubToken)

async function run() {

    // Get jobs
    const { data: pullRequest } = await octokit.rest.actions.listJobsForWorkflowRun({
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        run_id: context.runId
    });

    let failed = false;

    // Check if any of the jobs or steps failed:
    console.log(`Checking ${pullRequest.jobs.length} jobs`)
    for (const job of pullRequest.jobs) {
        console.log(`Job ${job.name} ${job.conclusion}`)
        if (job.steps != null) {
            for (const step of job.steps) {
                console.log(`Step ${step.name} ${step.conclusion}`)
                if (step.conclusion == 'failure') failed = true;
            }
        }
        if (job.conclusion !== 'success' && job.conclusion != null) failed = true;
    }

    if (failed) { 
      console.log("Failure");
    } else {
      console.log("Success");
    }

}

run();
```

When this is run it fails on the third step (`gradle assemble`). The last step is run since it has `if: always()` and it starts the NodeJS script.

In the NodeJS script the `jobs` I get is only the first job `build-and-deploy` of the first YAML file. And steps is only 1 step `Build service` which is still `in_progress` since the notifier is not finished. But is there a way to check if any of the composite steps failed?

Comment: One method I've found was to add ID's to all the steps in the composite. Then add a custom input for the notifier to "force failure" in that I could add like this: `FORCE_FAILURE: ${{ steps.setupGradle.outcome == 'failure' || steps.assemble.outcome == 'failure' }}`

This requires me to do this manually for each step. But if this is the only solution I'll add it as a answer later on if nobody comments.